# What is considered the best Java Suffix Tree implementation?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, suffix-tree, suffix-array

I need a suffix tree Java Implementation. After [some googling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857674/whats-the-current-state-of-the-art-suffix-array-construction-algorithm) I concluded that [the libdivsufsort C implementation](https://code.google.com/p/libdivsufsort/) is the best one around. Is there a Java implementation of the same (or almost as good) quality and that is preferably open source. The implementation should be production code, not  proof of concept code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969448/generalized-suffix-tree-java-implementation This might help you out, but the answers do not seem to have a very good solution.

Comment: [jsuffixarrays](https://github.com/carrotsearch/jsuffixarrays) is fully operational and seems to work correctly (I've used it quite a lot). That's suffix arrays (which you included in the tags), not trees though.

Comment: Thanks @jogojapan I'll check that one out.

Answer (score 1):

Try following some of the example in Java:
http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~weiss/dsaajava3/code/SuffixArray.java
http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/63suffix/SuffixArray.java.html

http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/63suffix/

Comment: these are suffix array not tree