# How to improve lambda expression in python suffix array

Tags: python, lambda

There is a code that uses lambda expression

```
def ComputeArray(text):
    # text is ended with $
    if text[-1] != "$":
        text += "$"
    sarray  = sorted(range(len(text)), key = lambda i: text[i:])
    print ", ".join([str(x) for x in sarray])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ComputeArray("AACGATAGCGGTAAACGATAGCGGTAGA$")
```

it correctly outputs desired array

```
28, 27, 12, 0, 13, 1, 14, 25, 6, 19, 4, 17, 2, 15, 8, 21, 26, 3, 16, 7, 20, 9, 22, 10, 23, 11, 24, 5, 18
```

How could I improve line

```
sarray  = sorted(range(len(text)), key = lambda i: text[i:])
```

so when increasing length of text I do not use lots of memory on a lambda expression?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Array.py", line 23, in <module>
    ComputeArray(text)
  File "C:\Array.py", line 11, in ComputeArray
    sarray  = sorted(range(len(text)), key = lambda i: text[i:])
  File "C:\Array.py", line 11, in <lambda>
    sarray  = sorted(range(len(text)), key = lambda i: text[i:])
MemoryError
```

## UPDATE

There is other code like:

```
sarray=[]
for i in range(len(text)):
  sarray.append(text[i:])
order=[i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(sarray), key=lambda x:x[1])]
print ", ".join([str(x) for x in order])
```

However is taking so much memory,

## Also I tried solution using library available on  https://code.google.com/p/pysuffix/

```
s = 'AACGATAGCGGTAGA'
s = unicode(s,'utf-8','replace') 
n = len(s) 
sa = tks.simple_kark_sort(s) 
lcp = tks.LCP(s,sa) 
print n print sa
```

although it solves the problem, it takes too much time with larger strings, ... do you know other library or a method to improve suffix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to build a suffix array. Luckily, there are already Python implementations of this algorithm: https://code.google.com/p/pysuffix/

If you must implement it yourself, think about what your code is doing:

1. Make a list of integers the same length as your text with `range`.
2. Apply the `key` function to each element of the list and store the result in a new list.
3. Sort the new list
4. Return the original integer associated with each element of the new list.

(This is also known as the [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), which a pretty neat idea.)

The point is, you're making a slice of your (presumably large) text for *each offset* in the text, and storing it in a new list. You'll want to use a more specialized suffix array construction algorithm to avoid this cost.

Finally, to address your original question: the lambda expression isn't the culprit here. You're simply running into an algorithmic wall.

> **EDIT**
>
> Here's a good resource for fast SA algorithms:
>   [What's the current state-of-the-art suffix array construction algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857674/whats-the-current-state-of-the-art-suffix-array-construction-algorithm)

Comment: I am using library like:
`
s = 'AACGATAGCGGTAGA'
s = unicode(s,'utf-8','replace')
n = len(s)
sa = tks.simple_kark_sort(s)
lcp = tks.LCP(s,sa)
print n
print sa
` however is taking too much with larger strings... do you know other library ?

Comment: I've added a link to more info. You may have to use a C/C++ library, perhaps wrapping the interface up to call it from Python code.

Answer (score 5):

> How could I improve line … so when increasing length of text I do not use lots of memory on a lambda expression?

That lambda expression creates a simple function. Most likely the bytecode for that function is around 8 bytes, and the cost of the `code` and `function` objects that get wrapped around it are maybe 80-128 bytes depending on your platform. Only one such function exists at a time, so your total memory cost is 8 bytes in the module, and another 128 bytes while this function runs.

So… do nothing.

To reduce memory usage, you have to find the part of your code that actually *is* using a lot of memory, and reduce that. In particular, it's most likely that you're creating an list of N numbers (with `range`), and then another list of N numbers (with `sorted`). You're also creating N strings of N/2 length transiently, which you don't need if you make your comparison a little more subtle. And so on. Don't do that.

- Using an `xrange` to replace the first list.
- Rewrite your algorithm so it doesn't need to build a whole sorted list, and instead generates the elements one by one in the first place.
- If that's not possible, consider using an `array.array` or a NumPy `ndarray`, which will at least eliminate the 24-48 bytes of "boxing" overhead for each number.
- You can write a cleverer key function that doesn't need to actually hold onto the suffix in its result object; instead, it holds onto `i` and to `text`, and has custom comparison operators that reference `text[i:]` as needed. Then at worst two of these suffixes will exist at the same time.
- If you're generating the values one by one, you can't use `str.join` (because it will create a list behind your back), so you will need a different alternative, like writing them to a `StringIO`. Or, in your case, since you're not actually returning anything, just dumping it to stdout, just `print` them one by one in a loop.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I agree.  Because we're guaranteed that the key function is only evaluated once on each element being sorted, it has to cache the results, resulting in enormous intermediate storage.  This is why `ComputeArray("a"*100000)` gives me a `MemoryError`, but `sarray = sorted(range(len(text)), cmp=lambda i,j: cmp(text[i:], text[j:]))` works just fine.  ISTM the OP has actually correctly identified the location triggering the `MemoryError`.

Comment: Would it be a way to optimize it a little bit?

Comment: @DSM: The function isn't taking up memory. The values that it returns, and that `sorted` caches, may be—as I already explained in the answer. But the way to fix that is to either (a) rewrite the algorithm so it doesn't use `sorted`, or (b) return _different values_ for it to cache. Changing the way it returns the same value will not help anything. Which, again, I already explained in the answer.

Comment: @abarnert: it's surprising how often the two of us don't agree on what's clear, but perhaps I'm old and set in my country ways.

Comment: @DSM: I'm not sure how to be clearer than "You're also creating N strings of N/2 length transiently, which you don't need if you make your comparison a little more subtle…" followed up by "You can write a cleverer key function that doesn't need to actually hold onto the suffix in its result object; instead, it holds onto i and to text, and has custom comparison operators that reference text[i:] as needed. Then at worst two of these suffixes will exist at the same time." If you can suggest a better way to put that, I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: @DSM: And I realize there's a good chance that the answer is just "strip out irrelevant stuff and say less in general", which I know I sometimes have a problem with… But examples can still help.